# Access query to pull records that have a value change more than a certain percentage

Tags: sql, ms-access, percentage

I currently have a table (MV Change) that pulls from two tables (Current and Previous) records if the market value from the two tables are different. In addition the query has an additional column that lists the difference between the two Market values, the expression used is `Expr1: [Current].[MARKET VALUE]-[Previous].[MARKET VALUE]`. I'm looking for two things;

1. Is there a query or expression I can create to pull only the records that change more than 15%? (Ex. If Current MV = 100 and Previous = 55  OR Current MV = 25 and Previous = 90 then the query would list the record.)
2. Is there a way to remove the ( )'s from the table results when the results are negative from that expression? (Ex. Current MV = 30 and Previous MV = 80 the results show up as (50) on the table not as 50)

Here's some sample data:

Current Table

```
ID Market Value 
1    $100   
2    $100
3    $100
4    $100    
5    $100
6    $50
```

Previous Table

```
ID Market Value 
1    $100   
2    $90
3    $50
4    $110  
5    $150
```

The query I would want pulls only ID 3 and 5 since both market values changed more than 15%. ID 6 would not be in it since there isn't a market value in the previous table

Any help would be appreciated.

My current SQL query is as follows;

```
SELECT [mv change].[id],
       [mv change].[new mv],
       [mv change].[old mv],
       [mv change].[change in mv],
FROM   [mv change]
WHERE  (( [mv change].[new mv] - [mv change].[old mv] >= 1.15 ))
        OR (( [mv change].[new mv] - [mv change].[old mv] >=- 1.15 ));
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Added some simple data, hope that helps

Comment: Please post the attempted query and desired result using posted sample data. Textual explanations are not always clear.

Answer (score 0):

Requirements do not specify Percentage of WHAT? Diff / Current  OR  Diff / Previous ???

Use `ABS([Current].[MARKET VALUE] - [Previous].[MARKET VALUE])` to get a positive value.

If `(Diff / Previous) > 1.15`  or `(Diff / Previous) < 0.85` Then report it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, here's the SQL language I've been working with to try to get my results. I'm aiming to get any MV changes that are a 15% change either positive or negative.

Comment: SELECT [MV CHANGE].[ID], [MV CHANGE].[NEW MV], [MV CHANGE].[OLD MV], [MV CHANGE].[CHANGE IN MV],
FROM [MV CHANGE]
WHERE (([MV CHANGE].[NEW MV]-[MV CHANGE].[OLD MV]>=1.15)) OR (([MV CHANGE].[NEW MV]-[MV CHANGE].[OLD MV]>=-1.15));